# In junit test file, failed to load context

Tags: spring

I created a structure for junit test

my class have this annotation

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext-persistence.xml" })


/dev/prjX/src/test/resources/applicationContext-persistence.xml
/dev/prjX/src/test/resources/application.properties
```

In the xml file i have

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="false"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${junit.db.driver}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${junit.db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${junit.db.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${junit.db.password}"/>
</bean>
```

In the properties file i have

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
junit.db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
junit.db.name=main_schema
junit.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
junit.db.user=admin
junit.db.password=admin
```

why my xml is not found?

Comment: Can you show stacktrace please?

Comment: stack trace  http://pastebin.com/25txsXPC

Comment: try to add a `/` before filename `classpath:/applicationContext-persistence.xml`

Comment: seem to work better i get now  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'driverClass' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'driverClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462842/org-apache-tomcat-jdbc-pool-datasource-is-no-longer-in-the-tomcat-7-dbcp-jar) how you configure the `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`

Comment: seem ok i used property name specified on tomcat web site

Comment: I have added my command as answer. Please accept these.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the xml file in the same package as the Junit test class or defined it as

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/applicationContext-persistence.xml" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `/` before filename `classpath:/applicationContext-persistence.xml`
and change the propertienames like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462842/org-apache-tomcat-jdbc-pool-datasource-is-no-longer-in-the-tomcat-7-dbcp-jar)

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="factory"
        value="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" />
    <property name="type" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ym" />
    <property name="username" value="admin" />
    <property name="password" value="admin" />
</bean>
```